# I cannot add a subpage in apache2

Tags: apache-http-server

Using a droplet, `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-209-generic x86_64)` and `apache2`:`Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server built:   2023-03-08T17:34:33`.

I have `myservice.com` working, how can I add `myservice.com/app`?

I have in `var/www/html/` the main page.
I made dir `/var/www/html/app` and put files there but it doesn't open, `Not Found` error happens (port 443).

How to tell `apache2` that there is a subpage at `./app`?

I've edited the config file in `sites-available` to be:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    ServerName myservice.com
    ServerAlias www.myservice.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dist
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myservice.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.myservice.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName myservice.com/app
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/dist
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myservice.com/app [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.myservice.com/app
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also ran `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/myservice.com/app`.

This is `apache2.conf` directory part:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride ALL
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've found solutions on the Web to this problem from 2005 that don't work, and I've found same solutions years later, eg. from 2017, that won't work...

Please tell me what further information I can give that could help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have in var/www/html/ the main page.

No, you don't. Your DocumentRoot is set to `/var/www/html/dist`, which means an `/app` URL would be expected to be at `/var/www/html/dist/app`.

(But if you specifically want to use a completely separate directory – i.e. if you want the "subpage" to live outside of your DocumentRoot – then `Alias` could be used to define an alternate location.)

Comment: Thanks! I moved `./app/dist` to `/var/www/html/dist/`. Edited config file for the app to have document root `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dist/app/dist`.  When I visit `myservice.com/app` though I'm getting `Index of /app
[ICO] Name Last modified Size Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory   -   
[DIR] dist/ 2022-12-13 04:18  -   `. The app opens if I click on /dist, or if I visit `myservice.com/app/dist`. I'll probably figure it out soon, but why would main page load under `.com`. and not `.com/dist` but for app it's the latter?

Comment: Why did you edit DocumentRoot like that?